# Registering single client as multiple applications in Spring Eureka

Tags: java, spring, spring-cloud, netflix-eureka

We are using Spring Eureka for service registry in our project. There are 12 microservices and each microservices serves 4-5 functionality.

For example a microservice called "MathOperations" serves functions like addition, subtraction, multiplication. With the help of Eureka, if I want to call one of the method, I will be invoking a REST call "http://MathOperations/addition". Now, the problem is, I dont want "MathOperations" to be there in url. I just want to call "http://addition", it should invoke the mathoperations addition method and respond with the result. It is ensured that, all the functionalities will have a unique name across microservices.

This is my thought process (correct me if I'm wrong), Can I register each functionality as a service to Eureka?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is not possible. Posted the same question as an issue in github. Seems like it is not possible. Refer [link](https://github.com/spring-cloud/spring-cloud-netflix/issues/1992)

Answer (score 0):

I don't think that is possible.
On Eureka the microservices get registered with their spring application name. So if you want to achieve what you are saying then you will have to create a separate microservice for each of your functionality - like addition, subtraction etc, get them registered on Eureka and then use them.